# How to create remote Maven project with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, raspberry-pi3

I'm doing an app for a raspberry pi 3 B, I'd like to write the code using Eclipse Neon 3 in my computer, and set on hot deployment, so the project itself it's inside the raspberry.

Right now I have connection to the raspberry from built-in Eclipse Remote System, I can connect myself this way, create a **normal** remote project and develop from my computer.

The trouble arises when trying to create this way a Maven project or trying to transform the previously created, normal project, into a Maven project.

How can I do that?

I need the remote connection, the compilation and launch of the code I don't mind to do it manually.

Comment: In my experience, you develop entirely within one machine. If you need to publish your code to an external computer, look at the Maven Wagon SSH plugin, for example

Comment: As it is possible to do this with a normal project, I'm looking for a way to do it with a Maven one. This way I do not need to be sending the code to the raspberry every change I do.

Comment: I don't see any significant difference between a "regular project" and one managed by Maven or other build system. You still have to install and run Maven remotely for all changes

Comment: I don't see it either but Eclipse does, when in Remote Systems perspective, it only shows 1 option to create project, which is a blank project without Maven. And if I do it this way, later on the option to convert a project to Maven gives error and does not work.

Comment: I've never used this Remote system thing, so I am not sure. My main point is that it would need to know the mechanics (e.g. ssh commands) to compile and run your remote maven project

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, right now in local to test we do it through CLI.

Comment: @Aleksandr The hot deploy is from the dev pc to the raspberry pi.

Comment: What are you deploying? What do you mean by *deploying*?

Comment: How do you package your app? Jar? War?

Comment: @AleksandrM Jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end it wasn't possible to interconnect the development machine and the raspberry pi to write the code from my machine live into the raspberry's hardware. At least not with a maven project.

If I had to do it again today, I would set a Jenkins server for CI and to be able to deploy the binaries in an easier way to test.